# ng-repeat not outputting results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm still new at this learning and I though I had it right, but I'm unable to output the fruits in my first app.
I'm using ng-repeat= "foods in body.fruits" to output, but nothing is showing. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="bodyController as body">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Tech Site</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Specs and Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How To Videos</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media <b class = "caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 " ></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 " >
        <div id="appleFacts" ng-repeat= "foods in body.fruits"></div>

        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-2 " ></div>  
      </div>
</div>

    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller("bodyController", function(){
        this.foods = fruits;
        });
    var fruits = [
        { name: 'Apples', calories: 65, totalFat: '0g', Saturated_Fat: '0g', Cholestrol: '0mg', 
          sodium: '1mg', totalCarbs: '17g', dietaryFiber: '3g', Sugar: '13g', 
          Protein: '0g', vitaminA: '1%', vitaminC: '10%', Calcium: '1%', Iron: '1%'
        },
        { name: 'Oranges', price: 5.95 },
        { name: 'Pineapple', price: 3.95 }
    ];
    })();
```

Comment: How do you want it to print anything if there's no template within repeat div? -.-

Comment: declaring `foods` in controller and trying to loop over `fruits` in the view. View has no idea what `fruits` are since they aren't defined in scope context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your App.js file, you need to utilize the **$scope** module. This is how you access properties from your js file in the html file. So it would look like:

`app.controller("bodyController", function($scope){
        $scope.foods = fruits;`

And then in the html:

`<div id="appleFacts" ng-repeat= "food in foods">
    {{food.name}}
 </div>`

And you could access any other properties from those objects with the syntax above: {{food.calories}} or {{food.price}} etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your controller and include it in the angular app module.

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  var BodyController = function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.fruits = [
      {name: 'Apples',price:1.00},
      {name: 'Oranges',price:2.00},
      {name: 'Pineapples',price:3.00},
      ];
  };

  app.controller('BodyController', BodyController);
})();
```

Once you have that, you then need to template the repeater logic in `ng-repeat`:

```
<body ng-controller="BodyController as vm">

...

<div id="appleFacts" ng-repeat="food in vm.fruits">
  <span>{{food.name}}</span>
</div>
```

See working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/TDh0Oes4KGeMrC7vNq3h?p=preview